# Few Concern: Migration domain controller 2008 R2 to 2012 R2 Domain

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, migration, dhcp-server

My Topic is Migration of 2008 R2 domain controller to 2012 R2 (All domain Controllers.)

Current Set-up.

I have 3 Domain Controller.

> 1. DC2008r201: Running As PDC and DNS Installed.
> 2. DC2008r201. Running as DC and DNS and DHCP Installed.
> 3. DC2012R201: Running as AD DC and DNS.(Windows server 2012 R2 server)

I am planning to move the DHCP Roles from DC2008r202 to the DC2012R201 server and then Remove the DC2008R202 Server from the Domain.

- Adjust all network device and for DHCP Relay Agent and Remove the DC2008R202 Server.
- Create One More New DC2012R202 Server and Move the PDC Role to The New Windows server 2012 R2 server.
- and also Remove the Last Legacy Server from the Domain.
  This whole process looks totally fine if i imagine but before i start to remove the legacy server's and update the forest , funcation and domain level to 2012

But There are Few COncern , which i wanna discuss.

1. What will be with the Computer and Server , who were Assigned the Static IP Address and Static DNS Server's ?
2. Do I have to go and check all this server's and Change this All settings with New Domain Controller.
3. Can i update my Schema , and Functional and Domain Level to the Windows server 2012R2 ?
4. What all things i need to be careful while i am updating the Forest and Functional Level to windows Server 2012 R2.

Please Share your Views , Thank you so much for your Advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Domain and Forest functional levels can only be upgraded to 2012R2 once you have Migrated all of your DCs to 2012R2. Remember that you can go back down to 2008R2 functional level once you have upgraded to 2012R2.

Don't forget to Transfer all the FSMO roles to your new DCs before decommissioning the older 2008R2 DCs.

Any existing servers with static IP info will need to be changed Manually or by using a script to point at your new DNS Servers.

Comment: Hey @Michael Brown, Thank for your Answer. 
i got that first i need to move all the domain controller to the 2012 and then i can Update the Forest and Domain level. 
i got another Question , what all changes will it make and how will it affect my Runinng exchange 2010 System

Comment: Is your exchange 2010 system staying on a 2008 Server?

Comment: For a while and after successfully migration of domain controller, I will migarate 2010 Exchange to exchnage 2013 and ofcourse the Operating system will be Windows server 2012 R2

Comment: then in that case the upgrade of the domain shouldn't affect your Exchange servers, I found this article for you as well: http://windowsitpro.com/blog/no-windows-upgrade-for-exchange-servers

Comment: Make sure you are running Exchange 2010 SP3 RU5 or later. Another site that might be useful to you https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff728623(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: Hey Michael, I am Having exchnage 2010 SP3 RU9 already on windows 2008R2 server and when i will update my Domain controller with forest and domain Level, 

I will install Windows Server 2012 R2 and Make the migration of Exchange server 2010 to Exchange 2013.
my Worries were, that if i update now my Forest and domain level, it should not affect the Running Exchnage setup